# Determine multicast senders with same IP

Tags: java, networking, port, multicast, datagram

I'm writing a multicast-based messaging program in java. For flow control of the messages, I'd like each member of the group to maintain a list of all of the other members in the group. I could do this by assigning each member a separate ID that gets sent along with the data, but I'd like to differentiate them based on address.

The only problem is, I am running many instances of the program from my local machine, so they all have the same address. Each member of the group runs a listener in a separate thread that listens for messages on a certain port of the specified multicast IP, and each sender sends to that port. Would it be possible to assign a separate port for each sender? Would the receiver be able to listen on all ports?

The receiver binds to a port using:

```
address = InetAddress.getByName(multicastIP);
socket = new MulticastSocket(this.port);
socket.joinGroup(address);
```

And messages are sent using:

```
packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
socket.send(packet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to differentiate them based on address.
>
> The only problem is, I am running many instances of the program from my local machine, so they all have the same address.

So you can't differentiate them based only on address.

> Would it be possible to assign a separate port for each sender?

Yes, if they all use different sockets.

> Would the receiver be able to listen on all ports?

The receiver doesn't need to listen on different ports. You only send to one port, you only need to receive on one port.

The problem with this comes if senders are also receivers. If that's the case it won't work: you will have an explosion of ports and you will basically have to multicast to all known ports, which isn't multicasting at all really. In which case you will need to devise a unique client ID, say a UUID.

Comment: At the moment, all of my receivers are listening on the same port, because all of the senders are configured to send to that port. If the port that the receiver is listening on is not the same as the port the sender is sending on, then it won't receive the packets. SO how can I have senders sending on separate ports if the receivers all have to be listening to the same port?

Comment: The port you send from doesn't have to be the same as the port you send to.

Comment: Does that take any additional setup to what I have in my code though? I just can't get the receiver to receive packets from a sender sending on a different port

Comment: As long as the sender sends to the port you're receiving on it should work. As this is multicast, presumably you haven't issued `connect()` on the receiving socket?

Comment: That's the thing, if there's multiple senders on my local machine, I have to have ALL of them sending on the same port if the listeners are to be listening on that port, because each listened must receive ALL packets from ALL members of the multicast group.

Comment: You keep confusing the sending port with the receiving port. They don't have to be the same.

Comment: You just said "As long as the sender sends to the port you're receiving on it should work", is that not what you meant?

Comment: No, it isn't what I mean. There are two ports. The sender is bound to a local port, with bind(), and sends to a remote port, with send().